# Uniquely identify buttons with javascript in shopify

Tags: javascript, dom, shopify

Is there a way to identify the search button on shopify website with javascript?

I have looked at various shops and cannot find something these buttons have in common. Is there some kind of api, so i can identify these buttons in order to add an event.

These two buttons are both search buttons, but from different shops:

```
<button class="search-header__submit search__submit btn--link site-header__icon" type="submit">
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-search" viewBox="0 0 37 40"><path d="M35.6 36l-9.8-9.8c4.1-5.4 3.6-13.2-1.3-18.1-5.4-5.4-14.2-5.4-19.7 0-5.4 5.4-5.4 14.2 0 19.7 2.6 2.6 6.1 4.1 9.8 4.1 3 0 5.9-1 8.3-2.8l9.8 9.8c.4.4.9.6 1.4.6s1-.2 1.4-.6c.9-.9.9-2.1.1-2.9zm-20.9-8.2c-2.6 0-5.1-1-7-2.9-3.9-3.9-3.9-10.1 0-14C9.6 9 12.2 8 14.7 8s5.1 1 7 2.9c3.9 3.9 3.9 10.1 0 14-1.9 1.9-4.4 2.9-7 2.9z"></path></svg>
<span class="icon__fallback-text">Submit</span>
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn--link site-header__icon site-header__search-toggle js-drawer-open-top">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-search" viewBox="0 0 37 40"><path d="M35.6 36l-9.8-9.8c4.1-5.4 3.6-13.2-1.3-18.1-5.4-5.4-14.2-5.4-19.7 0-5.4 5.4-5.4 14.2 0 19.7 2.6 2.6 6.1 4.1 9.8 4.1 3 0 5.9-1 8.3-2.8l9.8 9.8c.4.4.9.6 1.4.6s1-.2 1.4-.6c.9-.9.9-2.1.1-2.9zm-20.9-8.2c-2.6 0-5.1-1-7-2.9-3.9-3.9-3.9-10.1 0-14C9.6 9 12.2 8 14.7 8s5.1 1 7 2.9c3.9 3.9 3.9 10.1 0 14-1.9 1.9-4.4 2.9-7 2.9z"></path></svg>
        <span class="icon__fallback-text">Search</span>
      </button>
```

Comment: Can you modify the html for these buttons on Shopify? (I've never used it)

Comment: No, they may have nothing in common as you can use any HTML and customize them from within the theme template. Why would you need that?

Comment: @Vladimir adding events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this part of the theme can be fully customizable it's unlikely to find the option that would work in all cases. But most likely this the search button will be placed within the form with `action` to be equal to `/search`. So based on this you can try to use the following selectors:

**onsubmit**:

- `form[action^='/search']`

**onclick**:

- `form[action^=/search] button`
- `form[action^=/search] input[type='submit']`